# Turn singular row with interval into multiple rows which equal the interval

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

Suppose you have something like this:

```
Col1 Col2
a    odd from 1 to 9
b    even from 2 to 14
c    even from 30 to 50
...
```

I would like to expand the rows by separating the interval into individual row, so:

```
Col1 Col2
a    1
a    3
a    5
...
b    2
b    4
b    6
...
c    30
c    32
c    34
...
```

Note that when it says "even from", the lower and upper bounds are also even, and the same goes for odd numbers.

Answer (score 4):

separate Col2 into individual columns and then for each row create the sequence:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
   separate(Col2, into = c("parity", "X1", "from", "X2", "to")) %>% 
   group_by(Col1) %>% 
   do(data.frame(Col2 = seq(.$from, .$to, 2))) %>%
   ungroup
```

### Note 1

The input `DF` in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
DF <- structure(list(Col1 = c("a", "b", "c"), Col2 = c("odd from 1 to 9", 
"even from 2 to 14", "even from 30 to 50")), .Names = c("Col1", 
"Col2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Note 2

The next version of tidyr supports NA in the `into` vector to denote fields to ignore so the `separate` statement above could be written:

```
   separate(Col2, into = c("parity", NA, "from", NA, "to")) %>%
```

Answer (score 1):

with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>% mutate(Col2 = map(str_split(Col2," "),
                         ~seq(as.numeric(.[3]),as.numeric(.[5]),2))) %>%
  unnest
```

Or maybe a bit more readable, borrowing `separate` from @g-grothendieck 's solution:

```
df %>%
  separate(Col2,as.character(1:5),convert=TRUE) %>%
  transmute(Col1,Col2 = map2(`3`,`5`,seq,2)) %>%
  unnest
```

Comment: `unnest` is from `tidyr`, pipe and mutate from `dplyr`

Comment: To be entirely accurate %>% is imported by dplyr from magrittr and then exported.  See https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NAMESPACE

Comment: yes, I meant to use strsplit :), I'll leave it like that so it's more tidyresque

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`.  We extract the numeric elements in 'Col2' using `gregexpr/regmatches` into a `list`, then the get the sequence of elements by 2 with `seq` and `stack` it to `data.frame`

```
res <- stack(setNames(lapply(regmatches(DF$Col2, gregexpr("\\d+", DF$Col2)), function(x)
     seq(as.numeric(x[1]), as.numeric(x[2]), by = 2)), DF$Col1))[2:1]
colnames(res) <- colnames(DF)
head(res)
#  Col1 Col2
#1    a    1
#2    a    3
#3    a    5
#4    a    7
#5    a    9
#6    b    2
```